# UICollectionView with pagingEnabled - get content to stop at top

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

The collection view has a frame of 320x400, and the cells have a size of 320x320. The collection view scrolls vertically with `pagingEnabled = YES`. So at any time you can see one cell and part of another cell below. When you scroll up, I need each cell to stop at y=0.

Right now what happens is that each time you page upward, the cell stops at a higher position on the screen and does not stop at y=0. I think this is because the collection view pages based on it's own height of 400. How can I override this to stop on each cell?

I've tried subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout and overriding targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset, but I can't get it to work. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Flowlayout's minimumLineSpacing to 60 (400 height-320 height).  with paging on, that should give you perfect page.